# What is the equivalent syntax of this C++ code snippet in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

Because I do not know what this type of construct is even called, I do not know how to begin searching for an answer, so I am asking for it directly:  what is the C# syntax equivalent of this code from C++?

```
#define DoExit { \
    if (pDialog) delete pDialog; \
    if (lib) FreeLibrary(lib); \
    if (MadeNew) delete pRS; \
    return retval;}
```

This was taken from within a class method, so it's an inline declaration of a function to be called later.  In fact, here's an example of where it was used:

```
if (pRS->GetSize() == 0) DoExit
```

Note the lack of either `()` or a terminating semi-colon.

My first guess was some kind of inline delegate construct, but I am also not well versed in those, so it's but a guess.

So have at it, all you C++ gurus out there!

Comment: that is a C++ macro. there isn't exactly an equivalent in C#, you'd just have to write that as some routine.

Comment: Well, in C# you don't delete pointers, you let the GC manage memory, so in C# you'd just do nothing...

Comment: @Servy Unless those are mapped to resources that need to be disposed... in which case you might need to call `Dispose()` on them (though a `using` statement may suffice, as well)

Comment: @Servy While I happened to choose one with pointers, they are not all that way.  So at some point I'll need to port one that is doing things still valid in C#.

Comment: @ReedCopsey If the object implemented `IDisposable` then I see don't see the need to use a macro such as this.  You don't conditionally dispose of a disposable resource; you should *always* dispose of it and the `Dispose` method should just do nothing if there is nothing to dispose.

Comment: @Servy Typically, yes.  A straight port might need to check to see if the object was assigned yet (if this was in an exception handler, etc), and only call `Dispose()` if the object is not null... (Granted, a "clean" port will likely not need this)

Comment: @DonBoitnott Perhaps you'd want to use one of those as the example then, because, as others have said, there is no direct mapping of C++ macros in C#.  Depending on what it's doing you'll either need to find a way of writing it in the langue itself, rather than using compile-time macros, not do it at all, or find some 3rd party C# pre-processor that has a macro system built into it.  Without knowing the problem, it's hard to say which applies.

Comment: This is not idiomatic C++. It looks more like plain old C where there are no smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a macro in C++ - you basically just add that code, so the "actual" code would be:

```
if (pRS->GetSize() == 0)
{ 
    if (pDialog) delete pDialog;
    if (lib) FreeLibrary(lib); 
    if (MadeNew) delete pRS; 
    return retval;
}
```

There is no way to do the equivalent directly in C#.  You would need to expand the code manually, then port the expanded code as needed, or convert the macro to a method and call it.

Comment: Now I'm just being curious...since using a method for this would have been possible in C++, why use the macro at all?

Comment: macros expand guaranteed inline. So you are sure that there won't be any overhead of a method call (the inline keyword in c/c++ doesn't guarantee inlining). Probably not the reason why it is used in this example though.

Comment: With macro one can also do meta programming. So code generators. I'm not sure if the c preprocessor is turing complete, but you can get a long way with clever macro tricks. Of course, make sure that the person who has to maintain your code, is not known to be violent ;^)

Comment: @DonBoitnott I will say - most modern C++ developers tend to use macros less than they were used when they were developed.  This macro, for example, might not be necessary (or at least would be simpler) if using `std::unique_ptr`, etc

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of this code in C# is

```
;
```

because:

```
delete something
```

is done by the garbage collector, so non need to do it.
Libraries ( ie Assembly are managed by .NET framework, so strictly speaking you don't manage loading unloading of assemblies, unless you are loading unmanaged libraries )
The single portion you can find an equivalent is the `FreeLibrary` if you did a `LoadLibrary` `P/Invoke` somewhere else. In this case have a look here: [FreeLibrary](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FreeLibrary.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you've encountered is called a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/503x3e3s.aspx). There is no equivalent in C#.